# Memory Profiling through C#

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I have a c# library that P/Invokes into an unmanaged library. I allocate resources in the unmanaged memory, send them to the managed code, make a copy and then send it back for freeing by the unmanaged code. This apparently is leaking memory, so i want to a quick way in c# to determine the currently allocated memory and which changes as we free memory.

I tried using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PagedSystemMemorySize64`, it shows that i have a memory leak, but i want to make sure this property reflects that i freed the memory or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you making a copy? All you are doing is freeing the copy now, instead of what the original native code created.

Comment: I'm just making a copy in the managed heap, just to free myself of the burden of loosing the memory pointer. I then immediately free the memory before returning.

Comment: You're not "freeing yourself of the burden", you're freeing the unmanaged memory pointer right after you copy.

Comment: So, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post bits of the code where you allocate and free the memory.

Comment: You might take a look at http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial